# How to use proc format for columns in SAS output

Tags: sas, format

I have the following data

```
DATA HAVE;
input year dz $8. area;
cards;
2000 stroke 08
2000 stroke 06
2000 stroke 06
;
run;
```

After using the proc tabulate

```
proc tabulate data=have;
class area dz;
table area, dz*(n colpctn);
run;
```

I get the below output

[image: Priyamvada07_0-1617084939992.png]

I want to replace any values below 5 in "N" column and 0 in "ColPctN" column with "<5" and "0", respectively.

I have the below proc format code

```
 proc format;
picture count (round)
0-4 = ' <5' (NOEDIT);
picture pcnt (round)
0 = ' - '
other = '009.9%';
```

But I am not understanding how to use it in the data step to get the desired results. Please guide.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you defining COUNT as a picture format instead of just defining a normal numeric format?

Comment: @Tom This was already there in the code I am working on. I was assuming picture format is being used for COUNT and PERCENT because they are not variables in the dataset rather a column in the output.

Comment: Perhaps they wanted to round 4.6 to 5 and have it display as 5 instead of <5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the format as a `*f=<format>` crossing of the statistical keyword (`N` in your case). Because cells are intersections (crossings) of categorical values existing in the data you will not see a zero in `colpctn` unless you use the `classdata=` which predetermines which crossings should be in the output.

```
DATA HAVE;
input year dz $8. area;
cards;
2000 stroke 08
2000 stroke 06
2000 stroke 06
;

proc format;
  picture count (round)
    0-4 = ' <5' (NOEDIT);
  picture pcnt (round)
    0 = ' - '
    other = '009.9%';

proc tabulate data=have;
class area dz;
table area, dz*(n*f=count. colpctn);
/*               ^^^^^^^^^ format applied to N */
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Richard! This works, however I was wondering how to use it in proc freq, I tried using it this way ```proc freq data=have;
tables area * dz / list nocum (frequency=fcount. percent=pcnt.);
run;```. But it doesn't work!

Comment: freq and tabulate are different creatures so their features are different.  Create a new question if you want to ask about freq.

Comment: @Richard Done! Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66878045/using-proc-format-for-columns-in-sas-output

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK in SAS 9.4 you can apply your format to a dataset, but *not* to the content of the Output window (which is where you coppied the above table from). So you should first export the results into a separate dataset:

```
ods output Table=YourDsName;
proc tabulate data=have;
  /*your original code*/
run;
```

and then - as you say - format the `YourDsName` dataset in another datastep, or via `proc print` (as in the example below):

```
proc print data=YourDsName;
 format /*apply your formats here*/
run;
```