# Using proc format for columns in SAS output

Tags: sas, format, output

I have the following data

```
DATA HAVE;
input year dz $8. area;
cards;
2000 stroke 08
2000 stroke 06
2000 stroke 06
;
run;
```

After using the proc freq

```
proc freq data=have;
table area*dz/ list nocum ;
run;
```

I get the below output

[image: ![Priyamvada07_0-1617084939992.png]

I want to replace any values below 5 in "frequency" column and 0 in "percent" column with "<5" and "0", respectively.

I have the below proc format code

```
 proc format;
picture count (round)
0-4 = ' <5' (NOEDIT);
picture pcnt (round)
0 = ' - '
other = '009.9%';
```

But I am not understanding how to use it in the data step to get the desired results. Please guide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the result of `proc freq` as a dataset then report it as your wish.

```
proc freq data=have noprint;
  table area*dz/ list nocum out = want;
run;

proc print;
  format COUNT count. PERCENT pcnt.;
run;
```

If you want your `proc freq` output result just as your wish, not using an extra report or print procedure, you need to code a little more. The answer is about ods style and there is a very nice article about it: [Using Styles and Templates to Customize SAS® ODS Output](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi29/246-29.pdf)